# Proof of inverse function theorem

Tags: calculus, inverse-function-theorem

I'm reviewing old calculus notes, and we are given the inverse function theorem, note that invertible means injective here, and $f^{-1}:= f^{-1}(f(x))=x, \forall x \in D(f)$.

> *Theorem.* If $f$ is invertible on $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$, and $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $f^{-1}$ is invertible at $f(x_0)$, and $(f^{-1})'(f(x_0))=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x_0))}$, because
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_0)}{x-x_0}
> &=\lim_{x=f(y)\to f(y_0)=x_0}\frac{f^{-1}(f(y))-f^{-1}(f(y_0))}{f(y)-f(y_0))}\\
> &=\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{y-y_0}{f(y)-f(y_0)}
> \end{align}

**Questions:**

1. We used the first condition to be able to say that $x=f(y),x_0=f(y_0)$, but where did we use the second condition here?
2. What is going on with the indices of the limit after the last equality sign?

Comment: differentiability of $f$ is used in the formula for $(f^{-1})'$ and to prove the existence of the last limit

Comment: @Vasya How so? As far as I understand, $f^{-1}$ is itself a function, and we are saying that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ because the limit of $\frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ exists

Comment: The last limit is the reciprocal of $f'(y_0)$

Comment: @Vasya well yes, but the index, how did we get from $f(y) \to f(y_0)$ to $y \to y_0$

Comment: I agree, this is confusing. They should have used $y$ instead of $x$ in the first limit to avoid confusion and it should be $f^{-1}(f(x_0))$, not $f^{-1}(x_0)$

Comment: @Vasya can you write a full answer please? with a more comfortable notation

Comment: Besides the error in the statement that Vasya identified, another error is the conclusion just before it, that ‘$f^{-1}$ is invertible at $f(x_0)$’. I don't even know what it means for a function to be invertible at a point; and anyway, we already know that $f^{-1}$ is invertible on its domain, since it's constructed as an inverse. So what is meant here is probably ‘$f^{-1}$ is *differentiable* at $f(x_0)$’, even though technically you could leave that out (since it's implied by the following equation that references $(f^{-1})'(f(x_0))$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the proof like this:
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to y_0}\frac{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)}{y-y_0}
&=\lim_{y=f(x)\to y_0=f(x_0)}\frac{f^{-1}(f(x))-f^{-1}(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x-x_0}{f(x)-f(x_0)}=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}
\end{align}
We can make the last transition because $\lim_{f(x)\to f(x_0)}(x-x_0)=0$ since $f$ is continuous. I also think the statement of the theorem contains an error, it should be $(f^{-1})'(x_0)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x_0))}$ or (thanks to @TobyBartels),
$(f^{-1})'(f(x_0))=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$

Comment: Rather, the error in the statement is that it should be $(f^{-1})'(f(x_0))=\frac1{f'(x_0)}$ (which I think you were saying in your third comment under the question), because $x_0$ is introduced earlier in the statement as an element of the domain of $f$. But if we define $y_0:=f(x_0)$, so that $x_0=f^{-1}(y_0)$, then we get $(f^{-1})'(y_0)=\frac1{f'(f^{-1}(y_0))}$, so that is also a valid formula.

Comment: @TobyBartels: I agree, the best way would be not to use $x$ as argument for the inverse

Comment: @TobyBartels I get the crux of the argument now, but why we can change the index of the limit from $f(x) \to f(x_0)$ to $x \to x_0$ still eludes me. I don't understand Vasya's argument "we can make the last transition". I think an argument using the transference principle should be supplied here, but I'm not comfortable enough with the transference principle to supply it myself.

Comment: And by the transference principle I mean $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = a \iff \forall (x_n), x_n \to x_0, \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = a$

Comment: @Vasya the $f(x) \to f(x_0)$ becoming $x \to x_0$ has been driving me nuts for hours. This is my third or fourth passing of first semester calculus, so I'm really trying to not hand-waive anything. What property allows this to happen? Intuitively it makes total sense but I do not want to work with intuition here.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes: since $f(x)$ is continuous, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\delta$ is equivalent to $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$. If I have time to elaborate, I may expand on this but basically this can be shown using definition of limit and continuity.